# Ubuntu upgrade 11.10 to 12.04 - MySQL migration

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Some time ago, I tried upgrading my Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, but it failed on several points, so I rolled back the LVM snapshot.

One of the problems was MySQL. During the upgrade process, it started asking me questions like it was a new install, like asking for an admin password twice. MySQL is normally upgraded just fine, so what's going on here? There is nothing special about my MySQL installation.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu 11.10 originally contained MySQL version 5.1 and 12.04 had 5.5. 
Maybe it sees the MySQL not as an upgrade but clean install?